# Instructions for starting Varnish as root?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, varnish

A friendly soul in another continent who is helping me with a server issue gave me the instruction below. I don't want to bug him too much (plus he's probably sleeping right now) so I thought I'd bug the good people of StackOverflow instead.

He wants me to start Varnish as root. I've looked up the Varnish user manuals etc., and can't figure out how to do it.

Please be kind -- Linux n00b here. (Please also tell if the instructions can be used anywhere, or whether one should first navigate to a certain directory -- thanks!)

(My setup --- Ubuntu Server 12.4.3 in VirtualBox, trying to install a Plumi / Plone / Nginx / Varnish / Zope stack.)

> From the error below it seems that varnish does not start, or cannot
>   bind to privileged port 80. Can you try to start it as root?

```
2013/09/29 06:24:54 [warn] 2680#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /home/vb/plumi.app/templates/main.conf:11
2013/09/29 06:24:54 [emerg] 2680#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to bind varnish to port 80 you'll need to start is as root user.

i'm pretty sure your error message above is from nginx

either start it like this:

```
sudo /path/to/nginx
```

or this way

```
$ sudo su - 
# /path/to/nginx
```